# How to get std::numeric_limits<char>::min() value?

Tags: c++, types

How to get (correctly and/or readable value of) `std::numeric_limits<char>::min()`?

```
cout << std::numeric_limits<char>::min() << endl;
cout << std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << endl;
```

return

```
�
  // some character that can't be copied here, it looks like a rectangle containing four numbers in it
```

Comment: The characters under 32, and over 127do not have standard printable values (in ASCII, which C++ usually but not always uses) .  What were you looking for?

Comment: @MooingDuck ASCII 127 is also not printable (it's DEL).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to convert it to something that when streamed to `cout` will interpret it as an integer. E.g.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    int minc = std::numeric_limits<char>::min();
    unsigned maxc = std::numeric_limits<char>::max();

    std::cout << minc << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxc << std::endl;
}
```

I deliberately use `unsigned` for `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` just in case `sizeof(int) == 1` and `char` is unsigned.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part of the argument "sizeof(int) == 1 and char is unsigned". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user6076: it is possible that a `char` is signed that and an `int` is the same size as a `char`, so a signed int is required to hold the minimum value.  However, if the `char` is _unsigned_, then an `unsigned int` is required to be able to hold the maximum value.

Comment: @user6076: If `sizeof(int) == 1` but `char` is unsigned then `int` won't be able to represent all of the values of `char` so the conversion from `char` to `int` of the value `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` would result in an implementation-defined result which, whatever it resulted in, wouldn't be value preserving. To avoid this possibility I use an `unsigned` which (AFAIK) should be guaranteed to be able to represent all of the values of `char` in this case.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to understand the comments. The subject being casted is what `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` returns (right?), which should be some numeric value, not `char`, right? Why you need to safe guard the possibility of it being a `char`?

Comment: @user6076: In general the return type of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is `T` so `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` returns `char`.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thank you very much! So I can use anything that have larger max value than `int` to cast, such as `(long int) std::numeric_limits<char>::max()`, right?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the standard streams will output `char`s as characters and not as integral values. You can force them to do that by casting to an integral type that isn't a character type:

```
cout << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::min() << endl;
cout << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << endl;
```

Comment: Is there something similar to `cout << boolalpha;` that can change the behavior of `cout` so it outputs `char`-typed variables in some well-behaved form?

Comment: @Meng Lu: I don't know of anything like that.

Comment: Ok, then how to get the char with the min and max values in visually recognizable form?

Comment: @user6076 The chars with min and max values may not have a visually recognizable form (as your experiment showed). I assumed you wanted to print numbers, because the concepts of minimum and maximum only make sense when you're dealing with *numbers*, not *characters*.

Comment: For `char`, `min()` returned -128, and `max()` returned 127. Does the characters corresponding to 127 and -128 really don't have visually recognizable form?

Comment: @user6076: In ASCII (which most C++ uses) only characters 32-126 have standard visual characters.

Comment: @user6076: In some encodings, 127 maps to the ASCII DEL character which deletes the previous character. Most encodings don't map negative numbers, but -128 might wrap around to +128 which might map to the C1 control code PAD, a padding character. Neither are very visible themselves.

Comment: Thank you all. So what is your recommended reference for checking what characters corresponds to what character code? Is there some function I can use to determine the encoding system on the platform where my program runs?

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to an `int`.

```
cout << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::min() << endl;
cout << (int)std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << endl;
```